# How to process JSON output in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code snippet in .js file

```
$(function () {
    // KeyDates
    var url = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Intel.IIP.MDF.WCF/ProgramCalendarService/GetKeyDatesCalendarNew";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: null,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew) {
            alert(GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew);
            $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
        }
    });

});
```

How do i process the key value pair in GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew?

Comment: please show us your sample json response to help you. also on an unrelated sidenote, you need to write just `$.unblockUI` you are almost in an ajaxStop stage.

Comment: Could you show us the data structure of `GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew`?

Comment: [{"EventDate":"\/Date(1297189800000+0530)\/","EventText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.","EventType":3,"Logos":null},{"EventDate":"\/Date(1299263400000+0530)\/","EventText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.","EventType":3,"Logos":null} It is somethign like this when I saw the output of the WCF method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to know how to access an object's props. For that, use the `for in` loop to iterate over the object's values:

```
success: function (GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew) {
   for(var key in GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew)
       {
           var value = GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew[key];
           // do somehitng based on the key and/or value iterated
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, the argument of the success function is the evaluated JSON that was returned from the Ajax request. Therefore `GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew`, which you should rename to something like `data`, becomes the actual data that your server returned.

You can only process the data if you know its structure. One simple way of knowing this would be to do `console.log(GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew)` and then easily process it with a `for` loop if it's an array or `for x in..` if it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery "getJSON" function where you need to pass the url and specify a callback function.Your ajax call will be handled by the getJSON function. In the callback function, you can access the Keys as properties. A nice [example](http://webhole.net/2009/11/28/how-to-read-json-with-javascript/)

[Lav G](http://blog.lavgupta.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(GetKeyDatesCalendarDataNew,function(key,value){
    //do something here
})
```