# processing JSON output in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

[How to process JSON output in AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723978/how-to-process-json-output-in-ajax)

Reiterating on the same question asked yday(Above link),I seem to have more clarity now.

I get JSON output in 'data'
 var query = getDomainURL() + "/ProgramCalendar/GetJSONData";

```
  $.post(query, null, function (data) {...}
```

Now i Need to loop through the nodes and Identify 'Key' based on the names, and do some action for the 'val'

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
...
}
Can it be done using something similar with $.each, can you let me know the exact syntax?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server returns a JSON array you could use `$.each`:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    // item represents the current element of the array
    // here you can access its properties like
    alert(item.EventText);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I dont need to increment the loop or anythign like that ?

Comment: @user972480, no, jQuery does that. And it passes two arguments to the anonymous function: the index of the current element inside the array and the current element.

Comment: $.each(data, function(key, val) 

    {

    Html.Raw("['" + val.EventDate + "'," + val.EventType + ",'" + val.EventText + "']" );
    } I am doing something like this, Will this work?

Comment: @user972480, I don't know what Html.Raw is but the argument you are passing to it seems correct. This assumes that the JSON object has EventDate, EventType and EventText properties.

Comment: Yes, That's right. So just this $.each loop will do the processing for all the nodes in the result isn't it?

Comment: Hi Darin, the above usage didnt seem to work , WHen I Do a alert using $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            alert(val); val is printing one character at a time instead of node or propertis in each node, hence val.Eventtext would be undefined.Any suggestions?

Comment: @user972480, it seems that the `data` variable is not a javascript array. You could try parsing the JSON before: `$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index, item) { ... });`.

Comment: Sure Darin, will try that now. Also there is a requirement where i need to convert this JSON to an XML, Can you help me with that? parseJSON did work, thanks a lot.